# sparql query in java

Tags: java, sparql

I am writing a sparql query in java to select all records with a specific title. I am trying with this query

```
SELECT * WHERE { ?title rdf:type ?specific_title .}
```

but it doesn't work. Does anyone know which is my mistake?
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what "doesn't work" looks like.  Are there error messages, stack traces, or behaviors that might be clues as to the reason?

Comment: the answer from the server is
root cause

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3

Comment: Can you please post the entire stack trace you get in your code or from the server?

Comment: As I've asked already, please show an example of the actual RDF data, otherwise you are just keeping us guessing.

Comment: If the server is experiencing an IndexOutOfBoundsException while evaluating your query, then this almost certainly is a bug in the server software. Which triplestore are you using, and which version? You might want to contact the developers about this, see if there is an update available that fixes this.

Answer (score 2):

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3

It sounds to me like you are trying to iterate over the resultset and you are requesting a row that doesn't exist. Are you using Jena? If you are, it should simply be a case of:

```
if (ResultSet.hasNext()) {
    ResultSet.next();
    QuerySolution nextResult = ResultSet.nextSolution();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us an example of the data that you are running this query over?

Have you defined the `rdf` prefix (namespace) at the start of your query.

Also note that the value of an `rdf:type` property should be an `rdfs:Class` represented by its URI, e.g.

```
PREFIX rdf: http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
PREFIX ex: http://www.example.com#
SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x rdf:type ex:ExampleClass }
```

Comment: `?specific_title` doesn't have to be bound. OP's query (assuming correct namespaces declaration) is syntactically correct.

Comment: Drat, you are right. That'll teach me to post in a hurry. I almost never use SELECT * queries. Will fix.

Comment: yes i defined the rdf prefixes. i have some records with title, name, surname etc and i want to find the records with a specific title.

Comment: Please show us an example of the data, otherwise it's impossible to figure out the correct query.

Comment: my data is like your answer. with this query i find all the records. i want a query to find the records with a specific title e.g. a title added by a user that's why i tried with ?specific_title.